# Placing images with depth view

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, depth

I am a software developer, I use Adobe photoshop to customize images I'm using, I used to apply a filter long time ago   about 5 years and now I want to use it but the problem i forgot it's name and I can't find it anywhere, but I remember its functionality.

Let's assume we have a picture like [like this one](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TS_BLbtN36h5G3oY-F__QloVC7w2WDjkMC3Fbpk7UlHS4lhwZ5FdRUycz-lAfzV4WxZjGyNN3NaJwx9iKmm7QE6flExaAD9ckhuQJo80PSIqyLTmmlYhQj2K) with this effect it will allow me to draw a mesh on each Portrait This mesh will allow me to place images inside it so the new images will appear in the angle and position of the original Photo and when I apply this mesh will not be visible and the new photos will be placed in the position of the old photos with different angles.

please advice
thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that exact filter you are describing, but it's pretty easy to twist images to fit a perspective. Maybe you can use this method:

- Paste an image into your background image, right click it and *Convert to Smart Object* (or use *File > Place Embedded* or *File > Place Linked*).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to *Transform* the image.
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> and drag the corners of the image to fit the frame in the background image.

Since we made it a *Smart Object* you can always select the layer later, press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and refine the transformation without data loss. You can always double click the *Smart Object* to edit its contents.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't need that exact filter just anything can help me do what I described earlier. Thanks