# What is it called when you want to overlay an image at an angle?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, image-editing

I have close to zero experience in graphic design, but what is it called when I want to overlay an image at an angle?

I want to replace his screen - but his screen isn't flat. What is it called when I want to distort an image to fit the screen?

[image: example_screenshot]

Comment: I don't think there is a *specific* name for anything based upon its distortion. What makes you think there is?

Comment: @Scott Look man, I'm just trying to find the correct keywords to put into Google for a tutorial.

Comment: Okay. but why isn't *"overlay an image at an angle"* sufficient? `:)` As I posted, I don't think there's any *specific* name.

Comment: The magick word your looking for is "perspective matching" or if you work in animation/video industry "corner pin"

Comment: @Scott -  'Overlay at an angle' sounds like a rotation rather than a perspective distortion. [Rather amusingly, the guy's primary display has been turned towards the camera so much there's hardly any distortion on it… https://i.stack.imgur.com/U36IJ.jpg

Comment: Perhaps you can use [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/136848).

Comment: Note you could just have asked us how to do this. And get more out of your qestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is so much Youtube content that you can literally search without a specific term, just punch in what you need to achieve, like:

- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+apply+image+to+screen
- https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+perspective+distort

Yes, most of the times the screens will be "at an angle".

Comment: Alright thanks, "perspective and distortion" were the keywords that I wasn't aware of.